# Strange behavior of c# OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq

I have a c# program that extracts the squares from a sudoku grid. The extraction is done correctly, as shown here:
http://puu.sh/mbHl9/eefe8d7b07.jpg

I got an array of rectangles from aforge's GetObjectsRectangles() method, which you see drawn in the picture above.

I am sorting this array with the following line of code:

```
var rektsList = rekts.OrderBy(x => x.Top).ThenBy(x => x.Left).ToList();
```

and it is sorting correctly, except for one quirk, which is that the first element is placed fifth in the list, like this:

```
X: 435 Y: 998
X: 540 Y: 998
X: 335 Y: 1001
X: 643 Y: 1001
X: 744 Y: 1005
X: 245 Y: 1008
X: 845 Y: 1011
X: 941 Y: 1017
X: 1037 Y: 1022
X: 433 Y: 1097
X: 539 Y: 1097
X: 332 Y: 1099
X: 643 Y: 1099
X: 746 Y: 1103
X: 241 Y: 1106
X: 847 Y: 1108
X: 944 Y: 1113
X: 1041 Y: 1118
X: 431 Y: 1197
X: 539 Y: 1197
X: 643 Y: 1199
X: 329 Y: 1200
X: 747 Y: 1202
X: 237 Y: 1206
X: 850 Y: 1206
X: 948 Y: 1211
X: 1046 Y: 1215
X: 538 Y: 1301
X: 429 Y: 1302
X: 644 Y: 1302
X: 326 Y: 1304
X: 748 Y: 1305
X: 233 Y: 1309
X: 852 Y: 1309
X: 951 Y: 1312
X: 1050 Y: 1315
X: 427 Y: 1405
X: 537 Y: 1405
X: 644 Y: 1406
X: 323 Y: 1407
X: 750 Y: 1408
X: 854 Y: 1410
X: 229 Y: 1411
X: 955 Y: 1413
X: 1054 Y: 1415
X: 425 Y: 1512
X: 536 Y: 1512
X: 644 Y: 1513
X: 319 Y: 1514
X: 751 Y: 1514
X: 857 Y: 1515
X: 958 Y: 1517
X: 224 Y: 1518
X: 1059 Y: 1518
X: 423 Y: 1623
X: 535 Y: 1623
X: 644 Y: 1623
X: 753 Y: 1623
X: 859 Y: 1624
X: 961 Y: 1624
X: 316 Y: 1625
X: 1063 Y: 1625
X: 220 Y: 1628
X: 1068 Y: 1731
X: 645 Y: 1732
X: 754 Y: 1732
X: 862 Y: 1732
X: 965 Y: 1732
X: 534 Y: 1733
X: 421 Y: 1734
X: 313 Y: 1736
X: 216 Y: 1738
X: 1073 Y: 1841
X: 970 Y: 1842
X: 865 Y: 1843
X: 755 Y: 1844
X: 645 Y: 1846
X: 533 Y: 1847
X: 418 Y: 1848
X: 309 Y: 1850
X: 211 Y: 1851
```

Does anyone have an idea why this behavior is occuring? Did I miss something?

Comment: ...but the sorting seems correct, first you are sorting by Y, then by X, therefore the order is correct. I think you have to rephrase your question to make your issue more clear.

Comment: By fifth element do you mean `X: 744 Y: 1005`?  Or do you mean that `X: 435 Y: 998` becomes the fifth element of the ordered list?  I'm not entirely sure whether the list that you posted is the original list or the sorted list.

Comment: What do you mean? It looks like it's ordering by "top" then by "left", that is, by "Y" then by "X". If you thought the reverse, I'd expect you to be complaining about the third element first.

Comment: I think ViRuSTrinity's interpretation makes sense

Comment: It looks sorted to me.  What exactly isn't clear about which numbers go in what order?  Numbers are notoriously sequential things...

Comment: Sorry, I meant the 6th element, index 7. I was referring to:
    X: 435 Y: 998
    X: 540 Y: 998
    X: 335 Y: 1001
    X: 643 Y: 1001
    X: 744 Y: 1005
    X: 245 Y: 1008
    X: 845 Y: 1011
    X: 941 Y: 1017
It should be sorted in "Rows", so the correct order would be:
    X: 245 Y: 1008
    X: 335 Y: 1001
    X: 435 Y: 998
    X: 540 Y: 998
    X: 643 Y: 1001
    X: 744 Y: 1005
    X: 845 Y: 1011
    X: 941 Y: 1017

Comment: Index 7 is not the 6th element.  If you going off 0 index based collection, then index 7 is the 8th element.

Comment: @raketwissenschaftler: "index 7" would be the *8th* element in an array.  And it's still not clear what you're asking.  The values in that comment are *also* sorted as one would expect.  "Sorting" numbers means that they are placed in order from smallest to largest.  Which numbers do you think *should* be considered "smaller" or "larger" but aren't?

Comment: @raketwissenschaftler No, that would not be the correct order.  The correct order based on your sorting routine would be exactly as shown in the original list you've posted in your question.

Comment: Your list is obviously order by Y, and when it's a tie, by X.
When you have several sort fields, you can do that by ordering in the opposite order of precedence. You order by the least important and finally by the most important. If you think in terms of SQL, doing `.OrderBy(x => x.Top).ThenBy(x => x.Left)` is like doing a `ORDER BY Left, Top`. SQL abstracts this problem from you and allows you to specify the fields in order or importance. Of couse, if `Left` happened to be unique, all previous sortings have no value and are lost.

Comment: Okay, now I get it. I am just using ThenBy wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that Top means Y and Left means X, then the output matches the code.

OrderBy is done first to sort by the Y column.  After that, ThenBy is done to resolve ties in the Y column - this sorts rows that have the same Y value by the X value.

ThenBy is ensuring these tied elements are in order:

```
X: 423 Y: 1623
X: 535 Y: 1623
X: 644 Y: 1623
X: 753 Y: 1623
```

---

If you want to order by rows and columns, instead of by X and Y, then you need to translate coordinates into rows and columns.

One way to do this is to convert the coordinates to a score:

```
var rektsList = rekts.OrderBy(x => (10*x.Top) + x.Left).ToList()
```

This relies on the maximum error in 10*Y being less than the minimum difference in X.

Comment: Oh, so the problem is that the y-values aren't that unique?

Comment: Each series where Y is the same, that series is ordered by the X as in the very first 2 elements

Comment: The problem is that Y is not a row identifier, it's too unique.